# Prove that for any two integers $a$ and $b$ $ab(a^{60}-b^{60}) $ is divisible by $56786730$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

> Prove that for any two integers $a$ and $b$, $ab(a^{60}-b^{60}) $ is divisible by $56786730$

$56786730=2\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7\cdot11\cdot13\cdot31\cdot61$

It is easy to prove that $2,31,61|\ ab(a^{60}-b^{60}) $ using Fermat's little theorem for 61 and 31 and taking cases for 2. But I can't figure out a way to solve this for all the other factors. Can anybody help me solve this.

Except this, I would also appreciate if someone could share another method to solve this question which doesn't involve modular congruence as I haven't really studied that yet.

Comment: Er... $a=b=1$ gives the expression to be 2, which is not divisible by 61.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel lets just assume a,b<1

Comment: $3$ doesn't divide your expression unless $3$ divides $a$ or $b$.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/331538/forall-m-n-in-bbb-n-56786730-mid-mnm60-n60

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/349362/how-to-prove-that-for-all-m-n-in-mathbb-n-56786730-mid-mnm60-n60

Comment: @EthanAlwaise People have really solved it even though the question is wrong! (except I don't really understand their answers)

Comment: @OsheenSachdev In the two links you give above, there is a minus sign, rather than a plus sign, between the parens.  Did you mean to type $a^{60}-b^{60}$?

Comment: @B.Goddard my bad,I'll correct it right away!

Comment: @D.Thomine I tried that but it can only be done for 31 and not for other factors.

Comment: It can be done for the others factors as well, but I just saw an easier way. Just note e.g. that if $a^{10} \equiv 1 \ [11]$, then $a^{60} = (a^{10})^6 \equiv 1^6 = 1 \ [11]$...

Comment: @D.Thomine That's a great way...you can post it as an answer