# How to prove that for all $m,n\in\mathbb N$, $\ 56786730 \mid mn(m^{60}-n^{60})$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

How to prove $\forall m,n\in\mathbb N$:

$$ 56786730 \mid mn(m^{60}-n^{60})?$$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: There is a relation between the prime factors of 56786730 and the divisors of 60.

Comment: $56786730 = 2 \times    3 \times    5 \times    7  \times  11 \times   13 \times   31  \times  61$.

Comment: Little Fermat!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Notice that $56786730=2\times3\times5\times7\times13\times31\times 61$.

By Fermat's Little theorem, $61 \mid m^{60}-n^{60}$ as $m^{60}\equiv 1 \bmod 61$ and $n^{60}\equiv 1 \bmod 61$. [[Fermat's little theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_of_Fermat%27s_little_theorem) states that $a^{p-1}\equiv 1 \bmod p$ for a prime $p$ where $\gcd(a,p)=1$]. Using casework, notice that $2 \mid mn(m^{60}-n^{60})$ (i.e. either $m$ is odd and $n$ is even or both are odd). Either way the given expression is a multiple of $2$. Notice that other factors of $56786730$ are also primes.
Apply FLT again and again to finish the proof.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint** $\ $ Apply little Fermat, noticing that $\rm\displaystyle\ 56786730\ = \!\!\prod_{\large {\begin{array}\rm p\ prime\\ \rm p-1\mid\, 60\end{array}}}\! p$

Comment: See [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/893510/242) for a complete proof.

Comment: More generally see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/53183/242).