# Arithmetic: Prove that is multiple of 30

Tags: arithmetic

Prove that $n^{19}-n^7$ is multiple of $30$

I've seen $6$ can divide it because
   $$n^{19}-n^7=n^7(n^{12}-1) = n^7(n^6+1)(n^6-1)=n^4(n^6+1)(n^3-1)n^3(n^3+1)$$

And there are three consecutive numbers, so, at least one is multiple of $3$ and up to two even numbers.

But, how to prove that is multiple of $5$?

Comment: By [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/53183/242) (with $a=n, b = 1)$ we know $30\mid \color{#c00}a\color{#0a0}{(a^4-1}),$ which divides $\,\color{#c00}{a^7}\color{#0a0}{(a^{12}-1)}\ \ $

Comment: Dupe of  [Proving that $ 30 \mid ab(a^2+b^2)(a^2-b^2)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/53135/proving-that-30-mid-aba2b2a2-b2)

Answer (score 4):

Say $$n \equiv 0,\pm1,\pm2 \pmod 5$$ or, 
$$n^2 \equiv 0,1,4 \pmod 5$$ or,
$$n^6 \equiv 0,1,64 \pmod 5$$ or, 
$$n^6 \equiv 0,1,-1 \pmod 5$$

Therefore, $5$ divides at least one of $n^6,n^6-1$ or $n^6+1$, that is, $5$ divides $n^6(n^6-1)(n^6+1)$ .

And

$n^{19}-n^7=n\cdot n^6(n^{12}-1)=n\cdot n^6(n^6-1)(n^6+1)$

Hence given expression is divisible by $5$ and thus by $30$.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Notice, one should re-write & factorize as follows $$n^{19}-n^7=n^7(n^{12}-1)$$
$$=n\cdot \underbrace{n^6\color{blue}{(n^{6}-1)}\color{red}{ (n^{6}+1)}}_{\text{divisible by 5}}$$ 
$$=n^7\color{blue}{(n^{3}-1)(n^3+1)}\color{red}{(n^{2}+1)(n^4-n^2+1)}$$

$$=n^7\color{blue}{(n-1)(n^2+n+1) (n+1)(n^2-n+1)}\color{red}{(n^{2}+1)(n^4-n^2+1)}$$
$$=n^4\underbrace{(n-1)n(n+1)}_{\text{divisible by 3!}}\ \underbrace{n^2(n^2+1)}_{\text{divisible by 2! }}(n^8+n^4+1)$$
thus it clear that $\color{blue}{n^{19}-n^7}$ is divisible by $5\times 3!\times 2!=60$ i.e. it is divisible by $\color{red}{30}$

Comment: +1 for demonstrating that this is divisible by 60 and not just 30, so the question was easily improved in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer to the actual question: why is $n^{19}-n^7$ a multiple of $5$ ?

Divide $n^{19}-n^7$ by $n^5-n$ as polynomials:
$$
n^{19} - n^7 = (n^{14} + n^{10} + n^6) (n^5 - n)
$$
By Fermat's theorem, $n^5-n$ is always a multiple of $5$ and the result follows.

Somewhat surprisingly, $n^5-n=n (n - 1) (n + 1) (n^2 + 1)
$ is always a multiple of $6$ and so the argument above proves that $n^{19}-n^7$ is always a multiple of $30$.