# Prove that if $x,y,z$ are integers such that $x^2+y^2=z^2$, then $xyz \equiv 0 \pmod{60}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, pythagorean-triples

My approach:

let $x=3 \lambda, y=4 \lambda,z=5 \lambda $ where $\lambda \in \mathbb Z$ ,then $x^2+y^2=z^2 \implies $ $(3 \lambda)^2+(4 \lambda)^2=(5 \lambda)^2$

Since $xyz=60 \lambda^3$ & $60 \lambda^3 \equiv0 \pmod{60}$ $\implies xyz \equiv0 \pmod{60}$

Hence proved!

Is it correct?

Is there any alternative method of doing this?

Comment: This does not take care of the $5$-$12$-$13$ example, and infinitely many others.

Comment: $x=3 \lambda,y=4 \lambda,z=5 \lambda $ are not the only Pythagorean triples, have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple#Generating_a_triple.

Comment: And what about the third $\;(5,12,13)\;$ ? How would you express these three numbers as $\;3\lambda,4\lambda,5\lambda\;$ ??

Comment: @AndréNicolas,Martin,DonAntonio:THanks for suggestions, i'll think more on this.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/4318/proof-of-if-a2-b2-c2-then-abc-is-divisible-by-60.

Comment: See this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple#Elementary_properties_of_primitive_Pythagorean_triples

Answer (score 1):

Since for any $\;m\in\Bbb Z\;$ we have that $\;m^2=0,\,1\pmod 4\;$, this means one of $\;x,y\;$ is even and one is odd and then $\;z\;$ is odd, or else all three are even.

Also, $\;m^2=0,1,-1\pmod5\;$ , so either all are multiples of $\;5\;$ or else exactly one is.

Also, $\;m^2=0,1\pmod 3\;$ so either all or exactly one are multiples of $\;3\;$:

$\color{red}{Case\; 1}$ -- all three $\;x,y,z\;$ are even. Then clearly $\;3,4,5\,\mid\,xyz\;$ and thus $\;60\,\mid xyz\;$

$\color{red}{Case\; 2}\;$ --  $\;x\;$ is even, $\;y,z\;$ are odd : we then have

$$x^2=(z-y)(z+y)$$

and now check that no matter what remainder modulo $\;4\;$ both $\;y,z\;$ are, the above right product is always at least a multiple of $\;8\;$ and thus in fact $\;x\;$ must be a multiple of $\;4\;$, so again $\;60\,\mid\,xyz\;$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $ $ Using the [parametrization of Pythagorean triples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple) it reduces to $\,30\mid ab(b^4-a^4),\,$ which is case $\,p=5\ $ of $\,\ 6p\ |\ ab^p\! - ba^p\,$ for all $\,a,b\in \mathbb Z,\,$ prime $\:p\ne 2,3,\,$ which I [proved here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/53183/242)